# using setview under AlertDialog with long text

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I've been trying use setview with an added button under an AlertDialog along with long message text and positive/negative buttons. Whatever I do, either I don't see the positive/negative buttons or don't see the checkbox or the long text isn't scrollable. What can I do to show all buttons and checkbox and make it scrollable (als when phone is horizontal)?
full code:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public class StartGameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button customCheckBox = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        customCheckBox.setText("Custom CheckBox");
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(customCheckBox)
                .setMessage("Your long message here" + System.lineSeparator() + "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s\n" +
                "\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\"\n" +
                "\n" +
                "Section 1.10.32 of \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\", written by Cicero in 45 BC\n" +
                "\"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?")

                .setPositiveButton("start", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // START THE GAME!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancels the dialog.
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it.
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

-- edit --

looking for a solution in pure code, without xml's

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view.

```
public class EditNameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private EditText mEditText;

public EditNameDialogFragment() {
    // Empty constructor is required for DialogFragment
            // Make sure not to add arguments to the constructor
            // Use `newInstance` instead as shown below
}

public static EditNameDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
    EditNameDialogFragment frag = new EditNameDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Get field from view
    mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
    // Fetch arguments from bundle and set title
    String title = getArguments().getString("title", "Enter Name");
    getDialog().setTitle(title);
    // Show soft keyboard automatically and request focus to field
    mEditText.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Can be called like this.

```
    public class DialogDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      showEditDialog();
  }
  
  private void showEditDialog() {
      FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      EditNameDialogFragment editNameDialogFragment = EditNameDialogFragment.newInstance("Some Title");
      editNameDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
  }
}
```

Comment: your solution uses a fragment layout and view id, while I'm looking for a solution in pure code